# R function read.csv2 fail with error 'arguments imply differing number of rows'

Tags: r

With R, I am reading a simple file such as

```
data.frame(read.csv2("myFile.csv", header=F, sep="|"), colnames = c("user","product"))
```

and I get the error

```
arguments imply differing number of rows: 5462465, 2
```

When doing

```
data <- read.csv2(myFile.csv, header=F, sep="|")
colnames(data) <-  c("user","product")
```

Everything is OK. Why?

Comment: PS: I checked the file with a gzcat and grep, and there is exactly the same number of columns in each  line

Comment: If you really want to run everything on one line, use `setNames(read.csv2(...), c("name1", "name2"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `colnames` argument in `data.frame()` : see [manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html). So here you are adding a column to your `data.frame` which name is "colnames" and you try to add 2 rows : "user" and "product". This makes no sense.

I suggest you to use your working alternative that is perfectly fine.